# Revolut landing page animation on scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, scroll

I have been struggling to create the animation that is on revolut.com landing page. On starting scroll the background becomes white. I have tried some effects like fade but I want that linear transformation to white. I don't know any name for that transformation.
Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

One thind that is coming to my mind is expanding the size of the container of the mobile gradually keeping the size of the mobile image, so the mobile image will remain the same but the container size will eventually be of screen. Is it the right way?

Comment: Have you looked in to the GSAP Scrolltrigger library?

Comment: I can handle the part to trigger the animation on scroll. I just want to know how to do that white background animation starting from the edges of the absolute positioned mobile image going outwards.
Any help or idea is highly appreciated.